# Overloaded Methode value run with Alternatives in Sring Boot

Tags: scala, spring-boot, maven, jvm, vaadin

I'm new to Scala and i want to write a programm with Scala And Springboot, but i Become this Error in Application Class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer


@SpringBootApplication object Application {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        SpringApplication.run(classOf[Application], args)
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {}
```

and i become this Error:

```
Error:(13, 27) overloaded method value run with alternatives:
  (primarySources: Array[Class[_]],args: Array[String])org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext <and>
  (x$1: Class[_],x$2: String*)org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext
 cannot be applied to (Class[com.company.svgApp.Application], Array[String])
        SpringApplication.run(classOf[Application], args)
```

I'm Thankful for your help:

Comment: I guess the problem arise because you annotated both object and class with `@SpringBootApplication` annotation - try to remove this annotation from object and leave it in for a class.

Comment: That was True, I removed this annotation and i added  ```(args :_ *)``` to solve this problem, Thank's

Answer (score 0):

To Solve this problem, i should to edit code like that

```
object Application {

    def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {
        SpringApplication.run(classOf[Application], args :_ *)
    }

}

@SpringBootApplication class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {}
```